# Access form field value in controller (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, edit

So, i have 2 forms, one for creating, another for editing. In the new form, im storing every input in a variable from the model, like :name, so then later, in the edit form, its already populated with those fields.

Now, in the new form, i added some dynamic fields, which are not mapping to any variable in the model. Let me show you code. First i was doing this:

```
<%= f.input :oid, label: 'SNMP OID', as: :search, required: false, novalidate: true, input_html: {data: { autocomplete_source: get_oids_path }} %>
```

As you see, i stored the value in :oid.

But now im creating these fields, which are different:

```
<input type='text' name='var_1' id='var_1' class='string search optional form-control snmp_variable'>
```

Now, there is no attribute to store the value, since im creating fields dynamically. Only thing i have is the name of the field.

In the controller, i had something like this to populate the edit form:

```
def edit_monitor_category
    if @monitor_category.technology == "snmp"
      @monitor_category.oid = value_from_method()
    end
end
```

But now i cant do that, since now i dont have something like .oid to work with, i only have the the names of the fields i created, but i dont know how to get the values from this view. I had a variable in javascript in the new form with an array with all the values of these fields i created, but i cant use this variable in ruby since javascript is server side and ruby client side, so im kinda lost.

I heard something about before_action but reading about it i dont know how i could use it to do this.

new_form:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <h3 class="modal-title">Create New Monitor Category</h3>
</div>
<%= simple_form_for(:monitor_category, url: create_monitor_category_path, :html => { :method => :post, :id => :form_monitor_category }) do |f| %>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= f.input :name, input_html: { type: "text" } %>
    <%= f.input :description, input_html: { type: "text" } %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= select_chosen('monitor_category[category]', @categories.invert, label: 'Tab', required: true, multiple: false) %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= select_chosen('monitor_category[technology]', @technologies, label: 'Technology', required: true, multiple: false) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.input :custom_tab_name, disabled: true, input_html: { type: "text" } %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.input :custom_tab_unit, disabled: true, required: false, input_html: { type: "text"  } %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="snmp">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.input :oid, label: 'SNMP OID', as: :search, required: false, novalidate: true, input_html: {data: { autocomplete_source: get_oids_path }} %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row hidden" id="snmp_op">
      <div id="snmp_op_variables">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= label_tag 'SNMP OID (VAR1)' %>
          <input type='text' name='var_1' id='var_1' pattern="(\.\d)" class='string search optional form-control snmp_variable'>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.hidden_field :snmp_vars, :value => "1" %>
          <%= link_to "Add new variable", "#", :class => "btn btn-success btn-add-snmp-variable", :style =>"width:auto !important;", :id => "add_snmp_variable" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.input :snmp_oper, label: 'OIDs Operation', as: :search, hint: 'Do operations with previous outputs.', placeholder: 'Ex: (var1 * var2) / 100', required: false, novalidate: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row hidden" id="redfish">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= select_chosen('monitor_category[redfish]', @redfish, label: 'Redfish Commands', required: false, multiple: false) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row hidden" id="ipmi">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= select_chosen('monitor_category[ipmi]', @ipmi, label: 'IPMI Commands', required: false, multiple: false) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%#= f.input :custom_tab_unit, disabled: true, input_html: { type: "text", pattern: '[a-zA-Z]+' } %>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.label "Default" %>
        <%= f.check_box :default %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit "Create", :class => "btn btn-success", :style =>"width:auto !important;" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", monitor_categories_list_path, :class => "btn btn-secondary", :style =>"width:auto !important;", :'data-dismiss' => "modal" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% @index = 1 %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var snmp_vars_index = 1;
  //Enable or disable the custom tab name and unit inputs
  $('#monitor_category_category').change(function(e) {
    var option = $('#monitor_category_category option:selected').val();
    if (option == "new_custom_tab") {
      $("#monitor_category_custom_tab_name").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#monitor_category_custom_tab_unit").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $("#monitor_category_custom_tab_name").attr('disabled','disabled');
      $("#monitor_category_custom_tab_unit").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
  });

  //Enable or disable the custom tab name and unit inputs
  $('#monitor_category_technology').change(function(e) {
    var option = $('#monitor_category_technology option:selected').val();
    console.log(option);
    switch(option) {
      case "redfish":
        $("#snmp").addClass('hidden');
        $("#ipmi").addClass('hidden');
        $("#operation").addClass('hidden');
        $("#snmp_op").addClass('hidden');
        $("#redfish").removeClass('hidden');
        break;
      case "ipmi":
        $("#redfish").addClass('hidden');
        $("#snmp").addClass('hidden');
        $("#operation").addClass('hidden');
        $("#snmp_op").addClass('hidden');
        $("#ipmi").removeClass('hidden');
        break;
      case "snmp_op":
        $("#redfish").addClass('hidden');
        $("#snmp").addClass('hidden');
        $("#operation").addClass('hidden');
        $("#ipmi").addClass('hidden');
        $("#snmp_op").removeClass('hidden');
        break;
      default: //snmp
        $("#redfish").addClass('hidden');
        $("#ipmi").addClass('hidden');
        $("#operation").addClass('hidden');
        $("#snmp_op").addClass('hidden');
        $("#snmp").removeClass('hidden');
        break;
    }

  });

  $('#monitor_category_category').autocomplete({
    source: $('#monitor_category_category').data('autocomplete-source'),
    open: function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
  });

  $('#monitor_category_oid').autocomplete({
    source: $('#monitor_category_oid').data('autocomplete-source'),
    open: function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
  });

  //When clicking add variable, create a new oid field
  $('#add_snmp_variable').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    snmp_vars_index++;
    $("#snmp_op_variables").append("<div class='col-md-12'> <label for='SNMP_OID__VAR"+snmp_vars_index+"_'>Snmp oid (var"+snmp_vars_index+")</label> <input type='text' name='var_"+snmp_vars_index+"' id='var_"+snmp_vars_index+"' class='string search optional form-control snmp_variable'> </div>")
  });

  // Define your custom submit. Saves all oids into an array.
  $("#form_monitor_category").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    snmp_vars = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= snmp_vars_index; i++) {
        snmp_vars.push($("#var_"+i).val());
    };

    $("#monitor_category_snmp_vars").val(snmp_vars);
    console.log(snmp_vars);

    this.submit();
  });

</script>
```

edit_form

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Monitor Category</h3>
</div>
<%= simple_form_for(@monitor_category, url: update_monitor_category_path, :html => { :remote => true, :method => :patch }) do |f| %>
  <div class="modal-body">

      <%= f.input :name, input_html: { type: "text" } %>
      <%= f.input :description, input_html: { type: "text" } %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= select_chosen('monitor_category[category]', @categories.invert, label: 'Tab', required: true, multiple: false, selected: @monitor_category.category) %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= select_chosen('monitor_category[technology]', @technologies, label: 'Technology', required: true, selected: [@monitor_category.technology], multiple: false) %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.input :custom_tab_name, disabled: true, input_html: { type: "text" } %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.input :custom_tab_unit, disabled: true, required: false, input_html: { type: "text" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row <%="hidden" if @monitor_category.technology != "snmp"%>" id="snmp">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= f.input :oid, label: 'SNMP OID', as: :search, required: false, novalidate: true, input_html: {data: { autocomplete_source: get_oids_path }} %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row <%="hidden" if @monitor_category.technology != "snmp_op"%>" id="snmp_op">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= f.input :oid, label: 'SNMP OID', as: :search, hint: 'Output stored in var1.', required: false, novalidate: true, input_html: {data: { autocomplete_source: get_oids_path }} %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= f.input :snmp_oper, label: 'OIDs Operation', as: :search, hint: 'Do operations with previous outputs.', placeholder: 'Ex: (var1 * var2) / 100', required: false, novalidate: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row <%="hidden" if @monitor_category.technology != "redfish"%>" id="redfish">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= select_chosen('monitor_category[redfish]', @redfish, label: 'Redfish Commands', required: false, multiple: false, selected: @monitor_category.redfish) %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row <%="hidden" if @monitor_category.technology != "ipmi"%>" id="ipmi">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= select_chosen('monitor_category[ipmi]', @ipmi, label: 'IPMI Commands', required: false, multiple: false, selected: @monitor_category.ipmi) %>
        </div>
      </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.label "Default" %>
        <%= f.check_box :default %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit "Update", :class => "btn btn-success" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", monitor_categories_list_path, :class => "btn btn-secondary", :'data-dismiss' => "modal" %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<script type="text/javascript">
  // Enable or disable the custom tab name and unit inputs
  $('#monitor_category_category').change(function(e) {
    var option = $('#monitor_category_category option:selected').val();
    if (option == "new_custom_tab") {
      $("#monitor_category_custom_tab_name").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#monitor_category_custom_tab_unit").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $("#monitor_category_custom_tab_name").attr('disabled','disabled');
      $("#monitor_category_custom_tab_unit").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
  });

  // Enable or disable the custom tab name and unit inputs
  $('#monitor_category_technology').change(function(e) {
    var option = $('#monitor_category_technology option:selected').val();
    switch(option) {
      case "redfish":
      $("#snmp").addClass('hidden');
      $("#ipmi").addClass('hidden');
      $("#operation").addClass('hidden');
      $("#snmp_op").addClass('hidden');
      $("#redfish").removeClass('hidden');
      break;
    case "ipmi":
      $("#redfish").addClass('hidden');
      $("#snmp").addClass('hidden');
      $("#operation").addClass('hidden');
      $("#snmp_op").addClass('hidden');
      $("#ipmi").removeClass('hidden');
      break;
    case "snmp_op":
      $("#redfish").addClass('hidden');
      $("#snmp").addClass('hidden');
      $("#operation").addClass('hidden');
      $("#ipmi").addClass('hidden');
      $("#snmp_op").removeClass('hidden');
      break;
    default: //snmp
      $("#redfish").addClass('hidden');
      $("#ipmi").addClass('hidden');
      $("#operation").addClass('hidden');
      $("#snmp_op").addClass('hidden');
      $("#snmp").removeClass('hidden');
      break;
    }

  });


  $('#monitor_category_category').autocomplete({
    source: $('#monitor_category_category').data('autocomplete-source'),
    open: function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
  });

  $('#monitor_category_oid').autocomplete({
    source: $('#monitor_category_oid').data('autocomplete-source'),
    open: function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
  });
</script>
```

As you see everything is okay excepto for the fields i created that doesnt appear there, i dont know how to do it.

Thanks a lot to anyone answering.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some steps to accomplish this feature

1. Create a new migration in the model with a field called `extras` or something. This will store the dynamic inputs in your form. This field must be a `jsonb` type.
2. In new action from controller, you will receive all form inputs in params array. Notice that if you're using Rails 4+, you need to deal with Strong Parameters and maybe permit all parameters.
3. Once you receive the dynamic inputs fields, create a method that store all the values that does not belong to the model and assign it on `extras` field. After that in create action, just add the values to extra field and save it as json.
4. In edit action, you need to read from extras field, pass them to instance variables of model class, and use them into the edit view. When update action is triggered, just replicate the same that you do in new/create logic.

Answer (score 0):

If these forms are supposed to be the same, why not use a render in a _form.html.erb file to make them identical?

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1> new </h1>
<%= render "xxxx/form %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1> edit </h1> 
<%= render "xxxx/form" %>
```

Then, since these fields are not "persistent", they will appear in the edit, but not with the data entered in the new, unless you "calculate" them again.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal, but they not exactly identical, i can think of refactoring this in the future but at the moment it has to stay like that. So at the moment this cant be a solution, anyway thanks your four answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the notion of "attr_accessor". No need to be a base field, and you can calculate it

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessor :my_attribute

end
```

You can then either modify/calculate it in your edit method

```
@my_object.my_attribute = "xxx"
```

or use it in your form as a normal attribute.

```
<%= f.input :my_attribute %>
```

Comment: since im creating these fields dynamically, i could have 10 fields, i dont think is very DRY to create 10 attributes for later use, i thought about that, but since i dont know how many fields im going to create i dont know if this is okay.

Comment: Oh okay ! I think Javascript will be the solution to "calculate" the value of the fields according to the others.  However, for the fact that they do not appear in the edit, it is necessarily a problem in the edit.html.erb, but I can't help you without seeing it.

Comment: i added the forms to the post. I dont know if you will understand something hahaha. i have to find a way to display in the edit form all the fields i created, because if not i cant display the information entered before. But i dont know the way, if only i could access the variable in which i have all the values from these fields, i could do something like a loop on that array and build a div for every value.